# Limit of a composite function (homework help)

Tags: calculus, limits, function-and-relation-composition

I have a question regarding composition of functions.

The question I am asked is:

> $f(x)= \begin{cases} 1, & x \geq 0 \\ -1, & x < 0 \end{cases}$ and $g(x)=-(x-2)^2$
>
> why does
> $$\lim_{x \to 2} f(g(x)) \neq f(\lim_{x \to 2} g(x)).$$

What I would like to know is do I just state that the limit of $g(x)$ as $x$ approaches $2$ is zero and the limit of $f(x)$ at zero doesn't exist since the right and left hand limits are not equal. Or is the question asking for something else?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

The right hand side is indeed $f(0)$.

The reasoning for the left hand side is wrong. It indeed exists but it is not equal to the right hand side.

Try to find out what is $f(g(x))$ explicitly, then take its limit. To help you, think when does $g(x) < 0$ and when does $g(x)  \geq 0$.